# ¿Cómo resolver una Promesa después de un for que implementa otras Promesas?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas, ecmascript-6

Estoy usando el módulo PDF.js de Mozilla en una Promesa para hacer que cada página de un PDF sea transformada en un imagén JPG. Mi código crea los archivos de imagenes con ayuda del módulo fs, y es usado como una Promesa con ayuda de la función promisify del módulo utils. En este punto el código funciona de manera correcta, pero puse un Resolve después, y no está siendo ejecutado, y la Promesa se queda pendiente. ¿Dónde es que tengo que poner el Resolve?

He intentado al final de la función, pero temo que la forma en la que estoy manejando la Promesa hace que no sea ejecutado del todo, estoy atorado porque la implementación que tuve que hacer para hacer funcionar el módulo PDF.js

```
const CanvasFactory = require('./../../lib/canvas/canvas');
const pdfjsLib = require('./../../lib/pdf.js/node_modules/pdfjs-dist');

const fs = require('fs');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);
const convertPDF2PNG = (pdfFilePath) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfFilePath);
  loadingTask.promise.then((pdf) => {
    const maxPages = pdf.numPages;
    const convertPDFPromises = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= maxPages; i += 1) {
      const page = pdf.getPage(i);
      convertPDFPromises.push(page.then(page => {
        const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1.0 });
        const canvasFactory = new CanvasFactory();
        const canvasAndContext = canvasFactory.create(viewport.width, viewport.height);
        const renderContext = {
          canvasContext: canvasAndContext.context,
          viewport,
          canvasFactory,
        };
        const renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
        renderTask.promise.then(() => {
          const image = canvasAndContext.canvas.toBuffer();
          writeFile(`temporal/output${i}.jpg`, image)
            .then(() => {
              // TODO: add query to insert images in Database
              console.log(`File ${i} added`);
            })
            .catch(writeErr => {
              console.error(writeErr)
              reject(writeErr);
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            reject(err);
          }); 
      }));
    }
  })
  .catch(reason => {
    console.error(reason);
    reject(reason);
  });
  resolve();
});
```

Estas son las respuestas que tengo en la consola

```
File 2 added
File 3 added
File 1 added
```

Quiero saber porque la Promesa no es ejecutada.

Comment: Hay cosas extrañas en tu código. Por ejemplo, declaras `const page = pdf.getPage(i);` para cada iteración `i`, sin contar que tu incremento en el bucle es `i += 1` (¿no te gusta usar i++?). En cuanto tu pregunta, el `resolve()` según me dicta mi pensamiento debería ir justo debajo de la línea `console.log('File ${i} added');`. Sin embargo, me pierdo entre tanto `then()`. Creo que sería bueno usar un par de `async/await` para salir del enredo. Saludos

Comment: Otra cosa que puedo aportar, si usas Node v10.0.0 o superior puedes usar [`fsPromises.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_writefile_file_data_options), con eso no es necesaria la librería `promisify`, aunque advierto que en la documentación aparece como `Experimental`. Saludos